# Получение значения выпадающего списка при нажатии на элемент в PHP

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе элемента из выпадающего списка происходил вывод данного элемента без использования submit?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>
                <select size="3" name="first" multiple name="hero[]">
                    <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
                    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
                    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
                    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
                    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
                </select></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
            </p>
        </form>
        <?php 
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['first'])) {
        print_r($_REQUEST['first']);
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
// объявляем переменные и устанавливаем пустые значения
$eduErr = "";
$edu = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  

  if (empty($_REQUEST['first'])) {
    $eduErr = "Выберите героя";
  } else {
    $edu = test_input($_REQUEST['first']);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<?php
echo "<h2>Вы ввели:</h2>";
echo $edu;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: то, что вы хотите называется ajax и реализуется средствами javascript. PHP не способен отслеживать изменения которые вы делаете на странице в режиме реального времени. Ваш код заточен на перезагрузку страницы